# В конвертере JSF не удается установить Spring зависимость

Tags: spring, jsf

В конвертере JSF не удается установить Spring зависимость. 
Выводит ошибку:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to set property bo for managed bean bodyConverterBean
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com.otv.model.bo.BodyBO@18dd4d2 of type class $Proxy134 to interface com.otv.model.bo.IBodyBO
```

Пробовал инициализировать в Spring:

```
<bean id="BodyConverter" class="com.otv.converter.bean.BodyConverter">
    <property name="BO" ref="BodyBO" />
</bean>
```

И через @ManagedPropert:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{BodyBO}")
public IBodyBO bo;

public IBodyBO getBO() {
    return bo;
}

public void setBO(IBodyBO bo) {
    this.bo = bo;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Странно смешивать spring и jsf. А по существу вроде написано: то что хранится в #{BodyBO} не может быть приведено к типу IBodyBO. Вы уже убедились, что в #{BodyBO} точно IBodyBO?

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема управляемых бинов(@ManagedBean) - по средствам @ManagedProperty можно подключить только другой управляемый бин. В текущий ситуации можно попробовать применить управляющий бин (@Named) и механизм подключения @Ingect.